# Can a workflow that's already in progress be stopped and restarted if item is edited again?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

Let's say a list item is added and a workflow is triggered and goes into progress. While it's in progress the user edits the list item again. How do we stop the workflow that's already in progress and restart it again?

Comment: You want to do this manually or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the workflow that's already in progress, you could click the “In progress” state and then click “Cancel all Approval (2) tasks” like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify. Can we do this from the existing workflow logic?

Comment: Yes, you can do this for the existing workflow.